# Using arrays to detect a win in a gomoku game

Tags: java

I have made a simple GoMoku game where the player wins by either placing five pieces in row horizontally or vertically. The problem is that my program only detects the wins when the player starts from the outer most row and column on the board. I feel that my hasHorizontalWin and hasVerticalWin methods are flawed because I am lacking curly braces somewhere or perhaps that the count variable that I am using needs to be altered somehow. I am still fairly new to programming and this particular program was assigned by my professor. Thanks for any assistance you guys can give me. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Board {
    // I never actually use the EMPTY variable in my code
final int EMPTY = 0;
final int BLACK = 2;
final int WHITE = 1;
int player;
int[][] area = new int[19][19];

/*
 * This is method allows the player to play their piece
 */
void place(int row, int column, int player) {
    area[row][column] = 0;
    if (player == WHITE) {
        area[row][column] = WHITE;
    } else if (player == BLACK) {
        area[row][column] = BLACK;
    } else
        area[row][column] = EMPTY;
}

/*
 * The hasHorizontalWin method uses a count variable to count the pieces in
 * a row, but it appears to only count from row 18 and column 18
 */
boolean hasHorizontalWin(int player) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean isWinner = false;
    for (int row = 0; row < area.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < area[row].length; column++) {
            if (area[row][column] == player)
                count++;

            else
                count = 0;
        }
    }
    if (count == 5)
        isWinner = true;

    else
        isWinner = false;

    return isWinner;

}

/*
 * The hasVerticalWin method works like the hasHorizontalWin method except
 * it checks the columns, also starting from row 18 and column 18
 */
boolean hasVerticalWin(int player) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean isWinner = false;

    for (int row = 0; row < area.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < area[row].length; column++) {
            if (area[column][row] == player)
                count++;
            else
                count = 0;
        }
    }
    if (count == 5)
        isWinner = true;
    else
        isWinner = false;

    return isWinner;

}

// My hasWin method uses an if statement to check the two winning conditions
boolean hasWin(int player) {
    boolean isWinner = false;

    if (hasVerticalWin(player) == true || hasHorizontalWin(player) == true) {
        System.out.println("You Win!");
        isWinner = true;
    }

    else
        isWinner = false;

    return isWinner;
}

// My play method
void play() {
    // My scanner object to read input from player
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int turn = 0;
    while (hasWin(player) == false) {
        turn++;

        System.out.println(this);
        /*
         * By creating a variable called turn then using a modular operator
         * I am able to switch between players
         */
        if (turn % 2 != 0) {
            player = WHITE;
            System.out.println("White to play");

        } else {
            player = BLACK;
            System.out.println("Black to play");

        }

        System.out.print("Row: ");
        int row = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Column: ");
        int column = sc.nextInt();
        // Allows player to place piece
        place(row, column, player);

    }
}

// My toString() method to print out the board
public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    for (int row = 0; row < area.length; row++) {
        result += "\n";
        for (int column = 0; column < area[row].length; column++) {

            if (area[row][column] == WHITE) {
                result += "+o";
            }

            else if (area[row][column] == BLACK) {

                result += "+x";
            }

            else
                result += "+-";
        }
    }

    return result;
}
}

public class GoMoku {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Board game = new Board();
    game.play();
    System.out.print(game);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple changes required for your code to work:

a) Change the loop `while (hasWin(player) == false)` to  `do ... while (hasWin(player) == false);`

b) Change the logic for hasHorizontalWin() and hasVerticalWin() as below:

```
int count = 0;
boolean isWinner = false;
for (int row = 0; row < area.length; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < area[row].length; column++) {
        if (area[row][column] == player && count < 5)
            count++;
        else if(count == 5){
            isWinner = true;
            break;
        }
        else{
            isWinner = false;
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    if(isWinner)
        break;

}


return isWinner;
```

Comment: Sorry it has taken me so long to get back to you. Could these if else statements work in a while loop or is the do while loop necessary? I know the do while loop insures at least one iteration of the loop before checking conditions.

Comment: The changes you suggested have definitely put me in the right direction. The new issue is that now this program detects wins everywhere else except when connected to row 18 and column 18.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I was able to get the program working by moving the else statement up to my first if statement and turning the else if statement into a separate if statement.

Comment: The do-while loop is necessary as your first hasWin() was detecting win for the 0th player :) Also glad to know that your code worked after rectifying the other hiccups.